# Conservation International Hotspot Data

Tags: raster, data, heat-map

I am creating a Heat Map and need Conservation Internationals's Biodiversity Hotspot Data in GIS form. I have tried to find the data online, but have since been unable. Where would I be able to find this data?

Comment: Biodiversity Hotspots Revisited, Conservation International, 2004 http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=bc755b56fce8492d9817a9de49255f99